# NPM and NPX for react (at least) broken after windows update

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I updated windows a week ago or so. I found out a couple of days ago that I can't use NPM start or NPX create-react-app at all. I started to make changes but everything seems to go worse...

This are the errors I'm getting.

npm start

> ...@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

/mnt/host/c/.../node_modules/.bin/../node/bin/node: line 1: This: not found

---

npx create-react-app comeon
/mnt/host/c/Users/.../node_modules/.bin/../node/bin/node: line 1: This: not found

---

So far I reinstalled Node, NVM, Different versions of node, VSC reinstalled, Deleted environmental variables... changed paths, etc... I foresee full windows reinstall... What do you think?

Thanks!

Comment: I looks like a problem of PATH environment variable. Check that the one for node is still there.

Comment: Maybe check this too: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/29287

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use WINDOWS 11